# How to LEFT JOIN more than 61 tables pup MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I generated a large data query (one query ) more than 61 of type LEFT JOIN and now I can't continue how to solve this problem I need to add more tables.

My query is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'connt.php';

$id=$_GET['id'];


$sql="SELECT  * FROM topics
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN #########
LEFT JOIN ######### 
..ect


where topics.id = ? " ;

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();


$array = array();

while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}


echo ($result) ?
json_encode(array("code" => 1, "result"=>$array)) :
json_encode(array("code" => 0, "message"=>"Data not found !"));


?>
```

Also, is my way of working wrong? Is there a better way? Does this mean that the query will be slow?

Comment: I think you should revisit your database design rather than attempt this query

Comment: if you need to join more tables, there is something deeply wrong with your database design.  describe that if you want advice.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you mean to merge tables and differentiate data by a unique identifier?

Comment: @ysth Can you explain more bro?

Comment: not without knowing more about your database schema and the kinds of queries you are doing

Comment: More than 61 / Is this a mistake? @Chin.Udara

Comment: YES, like everyone says, it's a HUGE mistake. You either screwed up your database design or just misusing JOIN. Or both.

Comment: In any case, the limit of 61 tables in a join is literally hard-coded as a constant. You can't do a query with more joined tables in MySQL. See https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_const.h#L106-L107

Comment: So solution in this case is to merge some tables to shorten the query @YourCommonSense

Comment: Absolutely not. It should be not  "to merge some tables" but **completely revise the entire database structure**.

Comment: Really, you haven't described what the query is supposed to do, or why you wanted to use > 61 joins. So no one reading this can make an informed guess about how you should fix it. Telling you to "completely revise the entire database" is based on an uninformed guess.

Comment: Are you making individual tables for each user? I don't see how you'd have +60 tables.

Comment: I made tables of different brands, for example BMW, the first table, the second table for Mercedes, the third for HP..etc until the number of inquiries reached this limit. I have different schedules. Then I put the ID of the singular in the main table so that I fetch the data through the ID of the singular from main( topics table) @user3783243

Comment: I made tables of different brands, for example BMW, the first table, the second table for Mercedes, the third for HP..etc until the number of inquiries reached this limit. I have different schedules. Then I put the ID of the singular in the main table so that I fetch the data through the ID of the singular from main( topics table) @BillKarwin

Comment: so it must be a **single table** for all brands

Comment: Yeah, it would be way simpler if you used one table, with a `brand` attribute column.

Comment: Show us a sample of the FROM and a few JOINs; we may have something _constructive_ to suggest.